# Prevent java applet from being destroyed when container is hidden

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, applet

i have a bunch if DIVs, each containing some text, a java applet (yuck...) and some buttons; now i'm implementing a search function which dynamically shows and hides those DIVs, but whenever i set display:none to a DIV, the applet into it is immediately destroyed, as if it was removed from the html code, and then recreated when the DIV is shown again.
Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: What about visibility:hidden? Maybe combined with zero height.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: visibility:hidden seems to work! unfortunately, elements still take up space in the layout. is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: That's why I suggested also setting the height to zero

Comment: i did that too, but it still takes space, like it has a margin or something (it does not)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to prevent this?

*Don't* call `display: none` on the `div` element.  Try `visibility:hidden;` instead, or apply a style that shifts the applet off the visible page.  Something<sup>1</sup> like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Removing elements from view</title>
<style type='text/css'>
.plain {
}
.removed {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1200px;
    top: -1200px;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function show() {
    document.getElementById('target').className='plain';
}
function hide() {
    document.getElementById('target').className='removed';
}
var count=0;
function increment() {
    count++;
    document.getElementById('output').value=count;
}
window.setInterval(function(){increment()}, 1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Move the element off page</h1>
<input type='button' value='Hide' onclick='hide();'>
<div id='target' style='background-color:#F00;'>
<input id='output' type='text' size='4'>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Show' onclick='show();'>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Tested in FF, but not validated.

Comment: I've added an example using a JS based timer to show the result.  The timer 'keeps on ticking' even when the element is not visible.

Comment: i can't do that unfortunately. i tried using js dom functions to move the applet outside, but it destroys and recreates it (moron XD)    var p=document.getElementById("p"+id); document.getElementById("parking").appendChild(p.parentNode.removeChild(p))   any alternative? i can use jquery if needed

Comment: What is this rot with `appendChild`?  That is ***not*** what I was recommending!  Look again at my example.  Try it exactly as shown, except for swapping the `output` text field for the applet.

Comment: no no, i know it is not what you were recommending. i can't do that so i tried various solutions i found around the internet

Comment: *"i can't do that"*  So hire someone that can.  Either that or put more words into explaining *why* you 'cannot do that'.

Comment: because the applet is inside a div, and the divs are inside a table (that i can't remove), and even if i use visibility:hidden on a table row (and/or its content), it still takes up space and ends up looking like crap. right now i'm thinking of moving those damn applets outside, or remove them at all (unfortunately it's not something that can easily be rewritten in js)

Comment: The table complicates matters.  *"unfortunately it's not something that can easily be rewritten in js)"*  What is the applet doing?

Comment: it has to read stuff serialized using java serialization classes

Comment: @dosse91214: You're still talking about `visibility:hidden`, but have you tried the code example that moves it outside of view instead? To hide the table row, you can set height to 0px on it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps unfortunately, the behavior you describes is exactly the behavior of browsers these days.

You can still hide the applet, but you can't do it by hiding it's parent div.

First, you would have to put the web UI elements into a separate divs from the applet's div.  You can hide the web UI elements as you describe (set "display: none").  But to hide the Java applet, you set the style "width: 0px; height: 0px" on the applet element.

It is important to set the width and height of the applet's **style**, not the width and height **attributes** of the applet.

A hidden applet element looks like this:

```
<applet id="myHidableApplet"
        width="600px" height="400px"
        style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
```

Notice that...
  - the applet's **style** specifies `"width: 0px height: 0px"`, while
  - the applet's **attributes** specify `width="600px" height="400px`.

A visible group might look like this:

```
<div id="group1">
    <applet id="group1applet"
            width="600px" height="400px"
            style="width: 600px; height: 400px;">    <!-- visible -->
        <param> etc... </param>
    </applet>
    <div id="group1ui" style="display: block">       <!-- visible -->
        <input name="Name" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

When you hide the group, you would have to transform it to something like this:

```
<div id="group1">
    <applet id="group1applet"
            width="600px" height="400px"
            style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">    <!-- hidden -->
        <param> etc... </param>
    </applet>
    <div id="group1ui" style="display: none">    <!-- hidden -->
        <input name="Name" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I discovered this subtle but useful difference between the width and height *element attributes* vs the width and height *style attributes* while trying to figure out a way to deploy a completely hidden applet.  My applet has no UI.  My JavaScript simply calls methods in the applet when it needs to perform certain actions or computations that would be impractical to implement in JavaScript.  Sometimes this is referred to as JAHA, JavaScript And Hidden Applet.

Things to keep in mind:

- the <div> containing the applet must be visible... otherwise the applet will not load
- <applet width="0px" height="0px" > will not load the applet in Chrome.
- setting "display: none" on the applet's <div> causes the applet to unload (as you discovered)
- setting attributes width=0 and height=0 on the <applet> causes the applet to unload in Chrome.
- setting .style.width and .style.height is not the same as setting .width and .height.
- setting .style.width=0 and .style.height=0 makes the <applet> invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your site layout, you can position an iframe on top of the applet with some simple css and set the color to whatever your background is. http://jsfiddle.net/tQL93/3/

```
<iframe id="iframe_shim" class="iframe_shim" frameBorder="0">
</iframe>

<div class='applet'>
</div>

<button id='hideBtn' type="button" title="Hide Applet" style="width:100px;" 
onclick="hideApplet();">Hide</button>


function hideApplet(){
    var el = document.getElementById('hideBtn');
    if (el.innerHTML == 'Hide'){
        el.innerHTML = 'Show'
        document.getElementById('iframe_shim').style.display = 'block'
    } else {
        el.innerHTML = 'Hide'        
        document.getElementById('iframe_shim').style.display = 'none'
    } 
}
```